# Javascript and jQuery consecutive countdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I found a countdown script

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2dLn9sb4/)

How do I change hours, minutes, second and title with JSON object like this?

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "countdown 1",
        "hour": "0",
        "minute": "0",
        "second": "10"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "countdown 2",
        "hour": "0",
        "minute": "0",
        "second": "10"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "countdown 3",
        "hour": "0",
        "minute": "0",
        "second": "10"
    }
]
```

and show it one by one consecutively then redirect when all countdown done?

I am already using foreach loop, but it broke the countdown. This script is different than other countdown that use date.

Comment: why seconds are always 10 in your given output? isn't it should be 1,2,3,....

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant it's 10 seconds countdown 3 times.

Comment: what do you mean? if the countdown is of 01 hour then the seconds will go 1,2,3..... Could you please specify what you want to achieve by giving proper input, the expected outcome as well as currently what you are getting if possible?Or do you want 01 hout countdown will happen with 10 seconds time switch like 10,20,30,40...?

Comment: no, it just normal 10 second countdown. once Coundown 1 done, it will load Countdown 2 and continued until the last countdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use a for loop, instead you want a recursive function that can use if statements to continue or not.

For my answer, I have variables for the curTimer which represents the current timer's index in the loop.

maxSeconds represents how long the timer should go for based on the information in the timer.

thisTimer represents the data in the selected timer in the array.

If the current timer's index is less than the array.length -1 (arrays start at 0), then continue, if not then output done.

```js
const output = document.querySelector(".output");
let interval;
let curTimer = 0;
let maxSeconds = 0;
let thisTimer;
const timers = [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "countdown 1",
    "hour": "0",
    "minute": "0",
    "second": "4"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "countdown 2",
    "hour": "0",
    "minute": "0",
    "second": "4"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "countdown 3",
    "hour": "0",
    "minute": "0",
    "second": "4"
  }
]

const displayTime = () => {
  output.innerHTML = maxSeconds + " timer " + thisTimer.title ;
};


const timer = (timers, inc) => {
  thisTimer = timers[inc] 
  maxSeconds = (parseInt(thisTimer.hour) * 3600) + (parseInt(thisTimer.minute) * 60) + parseInt(thisTimer.second);

  interval = setInterval(() => {
    displayTime();
    maxSeconds--

    if (maxSeconds < 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      if (curTimer < timers.length-1) {
        curTimer++;
        timer(timers, curTimer);
      }
      else{
        output.innerHTML = "DONE";
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
};

timer(timers, curTimer);
```

```html
<div class="output"></div>
```